# How do I mutate over a set of variations for each row in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
| parent_sku |    sku   | stock_status | regular_price | tax_class | 
|:----------:|:--------:|:------------:|:-------------:|:---------:|
| ABBBOA01   | ABBBOA01 | instock      | 1299          | parent    | 
| ABBBOA03   | ABBBOA03 | instock      | 1299          | parent    | 
| ABBBOA02   | ABBBOA02 | instock      | 1299          | parent    | 
| ABBBOA04   | ABBBOA04 | instock      | 1299          | parent    |
```

I would like to mutate four variations for each `parent_sku`, `M`,`L`, `XL` and `XXL`. For example, the above data should be transformed to:

```
| parent_sku |    sku   | stock_status | regular_price | tax_class |    attribute_size   |
|:----------:|:--------:|:------------:|:-------------:|:---------:|:-------------------:|
| ABBBOA01   | ABBBOA01 | instock      | 1299          | parent    | M                   |
| ABBBOA01   | ABBBOA01 | instock      | 1299          | parent    | X                   |
| ABBBOA01   | ABBBOA01 | instock      | 1299          | parent    | XL                  |
| ABBBOA01   | ABBBOA01 | instock      | 1299          | parent    | XXL                 |
| ABBBOA03   | ABBBOA03 | instock      | 1299          | parent    | M                   |
| ABBBOA03   | ABBBOA03 | instock      | 1299          | parent    | L                   |
| ABBBOA03   | ABBBOA03 | instock      | 1299          | parent    | XL                  |
...
and so on
```

I have tried doing something like this:

```
data %>% group_by(parent_sku) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(attribute_size = 'M') %>%
  mutate(attribute_size = 'L') %>%
  mutate(attribute_size = 'XL') %>%
  mutate(attribute_size = 'XXL')
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to add it all of the sizes in as a list column containing the vector of sizes. Then use `unnest_longer()` to expand it out into rows.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# this should work with all the columns
data <- tibble(parent_sku = paste0("ABBBOA0", 1:4),
               stock_status = rep("instock", 4))

sizes <- c("M", "L", "XL", "XXL")

data %>% 
  mutate(attribute_size = list(sizes)) %>% 
  unnest_longer(attribute_size)
```

Which gives you the expansion...

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
   parent_sku stock_status attribute_size
   <chr>      <chr>        <chr>         
 1 ABBBOA01   instock      M             
 2 ABBBOA01   instock      L             
 3 ABBBOA01   instock      XL            
 4 ABBBOA01   instock      XXL           
 5 ABBBOA02   instock      M             
 6 ABBBOA02   instock      L             
 7 ABBBOA02   instock      XL            
 8 ABBBOA02   instock      XXL           
 9 ABBBOA03   instock      M             
10 ABBBOA03   instock      L             
11 ABBBOA03   instock      XL            
12 ABBBOA03   instock      XXL           
13 ABBBOA04   instock      M             
14 ABBBOA04   instock      L             
15 ABBBOA04   instock      XL            
16 ABBBOA04   instock      XXL
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How would this work for the rest of the row? It seems that I am specifying `paste0("ABBBOA0", 1:4)`, but the real dataset has about 200 unique `parent_sku` which don't necessarily follow a pattern?

Comment: It should just take every row and replicate it. So just use your data instead of the sample data I generated. All I was doing there was entering your data a quick way to show an example.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that there. Thank you so much, this works brilliantly!!

Answer (score 1):

here is a `data.table` solution

```
library( data.table )
DT <- fread("
parent_sku |    sku   | stock_status | regular_price | tax_class 
ABBBOA01   | ABBBOA01 | instock      | 1299          | parent    
ABBBOA03   | ABBBOA03 | instock      | 1299          | parent    
ABBBOA02   | ABBBOA02 | instock      | 1299          | parent    
ABBBOA04   | ABBBOA04 | instock      | 1299          | parent   ",
            sep = "|" )

sizes <- c("M", "L", "XL", "XXL")

DT[ CJ( DT$parent_sku, sizes, unique = TRUE ), on = .(parent_sku = V1) ]

#     parent_sku      sku stock_status regular_price tax_class sizes
#  1:   ABBBOA01 ABBBOA01      instock          1299    parent     L
#  2:   ABBBOA01 ABBBOA01      instock          1299    parent     M
#  3:   ABBBOA01 ABBBOA01      instock          1299    parent    XL
#  4:   ABBBOA01 ABBBOA01      instock          1299    parent   XXL
#  5:   ABBBOA02 ABBBOA02      instock          1299    parent     L
#  6:   ABBBOA02 ABBBOA02      instock          1299    parent     M
#  7:   ABBBOA02 ABBBOA02      instock          1299    parent    XL
#  8:   ABBBOA02 ABBBOA02      instock          1299    parent   XXL
#  9:   ABBBOA03 ABBBOA03      instock          1299    parent     L
# 10:   ABBBOA03 ABBBOA03      instock          1299    parent     M
# 11:   ABBBOA03 ABBBOA03      instock          1299    parent    XL
# 12:   ABBBOA03 ABBBOA03      instock          1299    parent   XXL
# 13:   ABBBOA04 ABBBOA04      instock          1299    parent     L
# 14:   ABBBOA04 ABBBOA04      instock          1299    parent     M
# 15:   ABBBOA04 ABBBOA04      instock          1299    parent    XL
# 16:   ABBBOA04 ABBBOA04      instock          1299    parent   XXL
```